# Nuxt I18n V8 in Nuxt 3 as plugin

Tags: plugins, internationalization, nuxt3

Can anybody help me with [Nuxt/I18n](https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/).
Integration in Nuxt 3 App as plugin?

In docs there is an example where options are passed in `defineNuxtConfig({..})`
But how can I make separate plugin like this

```
import en_US from '@root/locales/en_US.json';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ vueApp }) => {
  const locale = 'en_US'; //temp code for example

  const i18n = Some kind a i18n function here({
    locale,
    fallbackLocale: locale,
    messages: {
      en_US,
    }
  })

  vueApp.use(i18n)
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my `i18n.ts` file content

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from '../locales/en.json'
import tr from '../locales/tr.json'
import { defineNuxtPlugin, useRuntimeConfig } from "#app";
import { useMainStore } from "~/stores";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(( nuxtApp ) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  const ms = useMainStore();

  const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    locale: ms.miriLang, //config.locale.defaultLocale || 'tr',
    fallbackLocale: config.locale.fallbackLocale || 'en',
    messages: {
      tr,
      en
    }
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(i18n);
  // nuxtApp.provide("i18n", i18n);
  // nuxtApp.vueApp.provide("i18n", i18n);
})
```

you may define your translations in json files
`en.json` file:

```
{
    "button.home": "Home",
    "button.admin": "Admin",
}
```

you can use this in template section with `$t('button.home')` and in composition api  t('button.home') with imports:

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const {t} = useI18n();
```

if you want to to use i18n inside plugins folder you need to use it like this:

```
useI18n().t('shop.payment'),
```